# Using TextView's onClick to go to the next page with fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);

         tv.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    tv = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(getActivity(), Second_Fragment.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
                 });

           return myView;
        }
```

XML code:

```
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/processor"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Processor"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    </TableRow>
```

Error code:

```
     java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
07-13 04:47:09.009    1082-1092/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
07-13 04:47:09.236    1082-1092/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Answer (score 1):

First: You aren't starting a fragment calling:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(getActivity(), Second_Fragment.class);
startActivity(i);
```

The method's name is clear: startActivity(i); So, you should learn how to start a fragment instead starting an activity!

Second: Put the:

```
tv = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

before setOnClickListener(...);

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach a fragment via `startActivity()`, assuming your `Second_Fragment.class` is a fragment.  See this how to create fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

From the documentation, add the view where you want to fragment to go:

```
<FrameLayout 
     android:id="@+id/second_fragment"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then attach it to this view in your onClick via `FragmentManager`:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Add the fragment to the second_fragment view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.add(R.id.second_fragment, secondFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Okay, I'm not understand. can u show me the code look like. Thanks

Comment: FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Comment: Make sure that your Activity extends FragmentActivity. I'm not sure what your code structure looks like but this should put you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

you can use interface within your Activity and fragment 
whenever you click on textview within the fragment jst send data to the activity through interface and update the fragment from activity
for this you have to use onAttach() method